# How to reset an iOS application when a user clicks the "sign out button"?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am designing an iOS application where a user is presented a "sign out" button as the client wants that to be there.

However I am having a tough time working through the logic.

Should I:

1). exit the application at that point since the entire app runs on the premise of authenticated web service calls. (if so how do I make my app exit? )

2). Take the user to the initial splash screen where he/she is given the choice of login/register. (if so how do I reset the app back to initial screen?)

I know what I am asking is confusing so I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exiting from the app is not recommended. It would give the feeling of app crash to the user. You may use the second approach of sending the user back to the initial login screen after he sign outs. If you are using a navigation controller based approach you can try using `popToRootViewController` method of going back to the login screen(assuming login screen is your root).

Comment: You might also want to delete the URL loading mechanism's stored cookies so that future HTTP calls don't pass them to your server.

Comment: Funnily, Apple themselves call `exit()` when presented with an iTunes terms and conditions modal and you don't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Exiting the app is definitely not a good option. I would suggest you take the user back to the page where the user has the option to login or register. As an end user if he/she want to sign in with a different account if he/she can, it would certainly be the best option. No user would want to exit the app and launch it again to use them.